# Django queryset - order records by field value - show records with field_name=value first

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Here's the model:

```
TYPE_CHOICES = (
('x','Some X'),
('y','Some Y'),
('z', 'Some Z'),
)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    some_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    desc = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateFimeField()
```

I would like to get records with `some_type='x'` first then the others (both ordered by `date_added` in each "group")

Answer (score 0):

Using [`order_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)?

```
MyModel.objects.all().order_by("some_type", "date_added")
```

Comment: What if I want to get `some_type='y'` first ? This `order_by` above will return either `some_type='x'` or `some_type='z'` first.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'd like to know the same thing.